# Invalid parameter number Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo

I am trying to pass some parameters to my Laravel query Builder but it returns Invalid parameter number Error

```php
$tapuser = "";
if (@Session::get('user_admin_sub') > 0) {
    $params['user_admin_sub'] = intval(Session::get('user_admin_sub'));
    $tapuser = "and notes.user_id = :user_admin_sub";
}
$params['start'] = $request->start;
$params['end'] = $request->end;
$params['userId'] = Auth::id();
$data = [];

$confirmation_call = DB::select("select count(*) as nbr from orders, notes 
    where orders.id = notes.order_id 
    and orders.user_id=:userId and notes.note like '%CC: %'
    and notes.user_id=:userId 
    and (notes.created_at BETWEEN :start AND :end) $tapuser", $params);
```

Comment: "You must include a unique parameter marker for each value you wish to pass in to the statement when you call PDOStatement::execute(). You cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name more than once in a prepared statement, unless emulation mode is on. "   https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: can you clarify more please ? @lagbox

Comment: you can't reuse `:userId` in the prepared statement, you would need another parameter or you would have to turn on emulation mode  ... query builder uses PDO to prepare and execute the queries

Comment: but even if i use it only one time it returns this error 'Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined ' @lagbox

Comment: i have 3 parameters as you see and i pass them the same way you see

Comment: You're using `:userId` twice in your query. You cannot use the same parameter multiple times in one query. Each one must be named differently

Comment: if you try to use reuse `:userId` you will get that parameter number error, if you pass to many parameters you will also get that error ... you just have to make sure the amount of parameters used matches what you pass as the parameters (and not reusing a paremeter; as it is counting actual place holders in the statement not their names)

Comment: @Sinor You've nailed it, thanks.